# What does "with their own command" mean in the context of playing a sport?

Tags: phrase-meaning, terminology

What does this "play with their own command" mean?

> Captain’s Cup Navy Sports Week
>   Monday-Friday, September 30 – October 4 • 0900 Various Locations
>   Participants must **play with their own command.** Events are softball, flag football, soccer, volleyball and basketball. Commands must register by 1700 Wednesday, September 26 at the Fitness, Adult Sports, and Deployed Forces Office. Coaches/Captain’s meeting on site before each event at 0845.

Comment: Just a suggestion: please make your title more specific .

Answer (score 2):

This is an announcement for a recreational sports tournament on a military base. For this competition, members assigned to, say, the Airlift Command cannot be on the same sports team team as members assigned to the Communications Command. Each team must be comprised of players who are all assigned to the same command.

Comment: interesting - at first I thought this was British English until I read your answer. +1 :) (Live near a navy base, but never was in myself.) Makes me wonder if we need a "Jargon" tag ?